# how can i determine if anything at the given url does exist

Tags: python, http, url

how can i determine if anything at the given url does exist in the web using python? it can be a html page or a pdf file, shouldnt be matter.
ive tried the solution written in this page http://code.activestate.com/recipes/101276/
but it just returns a 1 when its a pdf file or anything.

Comment: The code you linked to seems to do what you want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to check HTTP response code. Python example:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
code = urlopen("http://example.com/").code
```

4xx and 5xx code probably mean that you cannot get anything from this URL. 4xx status codes describe client errors (like "404 Not found") and 5xx status codes describe server errors (like "500 Internal server error"):

```
if (code / 100 >= 4):
   print "Nothing there."
```

Links:

- [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
- [urllib2 reference](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: `urlopen` sends a `GET` request, and the server will return the whole content for that URL. Personally I think use `HTTPConnection`/`HTTPSConnection` to build a `HEAD` request is better, which will save a lot net traffic.

Comment: Good point. I agree that `HEAD` is often better and will save traffic.  So I upvoted Yacoby's answer. However, `urllib2.urlopen` is radically easy to use and saves lines of code (no need to split URL into server/path pair, for instance). `GET` costs may be acceptable in many cases.

Comment: Probably You should avoid redirections codes also.

Answer (score 9):

Send a HEAD request

```
import httplib 
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url) 
connection.request('HEAD', '/') 
response = connection.getresponse() 
if response.status == 200:
    print "Resource exists"
```

Comment: i get an error for this answer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cad/eclipse/wsp/pyCrawler/src/pyCrawler/pyCrawler.py", line 63, in <module>
    print httpExists('http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=5912')
  File "/home/cad/eclipse/wsp/pyCrawler/src/pyCrawler/pyCrawler.py", line 25, in httpExists
    c = httplib.HTTPConnection(url) 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 656, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 668, in _set_hostport
 .....

Comment: For the record, this one does use HTTP/1.1 and so does work on Slashdot.

Answer (score 2):

The `httplib` in that example is using HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1, and as such Slashdot is returning a status code 301 instead of 200. I would recommend using `urllib2`, and also probably checking for codes `20*` and `30*`.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) for `httplib` states:

> It is normally not used directly — the module [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) uses it to handle URLs that use HTTP and HTTPS.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The `HTTP` class is retained only for backward compatibility with 1.5.2. It should not be used in new code. Refer to the online docstrings for usage.

So yes. `urllib` is the way to open URLs in Python — an HTTP/1.0 client won't get very far on modern web servers.

(Also, a PDF link works for me.)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the version of HTTP. Actually it is because `httplib.HTTP` skipped the host field in the request.

You can test by:
     $ telnet slashdot.org 80
     HEAD / HTTP/1.0
     Host: slashdot.org

Comment: What I really meant is that a 1.0 request isn't *required* to include the host header.

Answer (score 0):

This solution returns 1 because server is sending 200 OK response.

There's something wrong with your server. It should return 404 if the file doesn't exist.